# What's causing dbus-daemon to take up over 3GB of RAM?

Tags: debian, logs, memory, ram, d-bus

dbus-daemon is consuming a lot of memory on my Debian 9/KDE machine. How can I find out why?

---

The amount of allocated RAM is not changing anymore: it's stable at well over 3GB. I already tried closing my browser which uses most memory as well as any other applications I had opened (not many). I also tried removing some widgets from my desktop.

I also ran `dbus-monitor` which outputs:

```
signal time=.. sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.152 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.152"

signal time=.. sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.152 serial=4 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.152"
```

and skimmed over the thousands of entries in `sudo kate /var/log/syslog`. But I still don't see what's causing this.

What to look for in syslog? Is there a log that gets enabled once processes exceed e.g. specified resource thresholds? What is causing this memory-usage?

Should I run `sudo service dbus restart`?

Comment: You need to clarify _which_ and _whose_ `dbus-daemon` this is.

Comment: /usr/bin/dbus-daemon and my username. Or what do you mean? Also it just reduced by around half of the RAM. Otherwise the allocated amount doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

The dbus-deamon is the messenger between applications. It may be that the dbus-deamon is being flooded with chatter between two or more applications on the system, for one reason or another.

- I would close all non-essential apps one at a time while monitoring the resource use.
- The messages between apps may not even be error related, so they may not be reported by the monitor unless you make it more verbose.
- I would then attempt to resart the dbus-deamon only if the above does not bare fruit.

If you find that there is an app/apps that is causing this, I would then try to figure why those apps are behaving that way. You could then look through logs about that/those programs and find the cause.